# get image form URL in ios not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post, uiimageview

I tried post image to Server via JSON .First image convert to `NSData` and then `NSData` to `NSString` Via Base64.

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(firstimage1.image);
  strEncoded = [Base64 encode:imageData];
```

and then `NSString(strEncoded)` pass to JSON URL.

Now I need get same  image.  I tired getting like this

```
NSString *geting =[diction valueForKey:@"dealimage"];
NSData *getdata=[[NSData alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:geting]];
NSLog(@"good day %@",getdata);
dataimages=[UIImage imageWithData:getdata];
```

First `NSString` convert to `NSData` via Base64 and then `NSData` pass to `UIImage(dataimages)`. but I am not getting. I am getting this error:-

```
ImageIO: PNG invalid PNG file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk
Aug  4 17:45:43 Himansus-Mac-Pro.local DealsStart[4365] <Error>: ImageIO: PNG invalid code lengths set
Aug  4 17:45:43 Himansus-Mac-Pro.local DealsStart[4365] <Error>: ImageIO: PNG invalid PNG file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk
Aug  4 17:45:43 Himansus-Mac-Pro.local DealsStart[4365] <Error>: ImageIO: PNG invalid code lengths set
```

Please give me any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
NSString *geting =[diction valueForKey:@"dealimage"];
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:geting options:0];

NSLog(@"%@", decodedData);
```

may be its helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have to get image from JSON dictionary..
So you need to use base64 decoder rather then URL, it convert encoded string to NSData. For that you need to add base64 lib. which will be available at [Lib](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64)

Just have  to add one sentence

NSData *image = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"strImage"]];
imView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:image];

Thats it.

Comment: thanks for reply when used you code i face one problem when post image like this   strEncoded = [Base64 encode:imageData];i get this error Base64 undeclared error.But i add Base64.h and Base64.m file to my project So Please give me any idea